# Redis text search special character using jedis ftsearch method

Tags: java, redis, jedis

How can I search exact text search in redis which will contain special character like (:,_,$,#,;,!,?)
1.I can't store that field in a tag we have a huge .text file
2.i have tried with escape character but not working

Eg. seachTerm= abc:xyz?test/abc.json

Comment: Can you share one example what's the content on these TEXT file and the use case? Why you can't map as TAGs?